# How can I get a libtiff TIFF object from a MagickWand object (in C)?

Tags: c++, c, imagemagick, tiff, tesseract

How can I get a libtiff TIFF object from a MagickWand object (in C)?

I want to open any given image type with ImageMagick and run tesseract on it. Tesseract seems to use libtiff for it's IO, ImageMagick seems to use libtiff for it's tiff handling, so I figured I should somehow be able to use ImageMagick with tesseract without meddling in the filesystem and additional unessesary disk IO.

Thanks,
Chenz

Answer (score 0):

Look at BeginPageUpright() in Tesseract.  It takes the image width, height, bpp, and the raw uncompressed data, which you should be able to get from ImageMagick.